# Multicast. Does the source of music need an address from MADCAP and what about the receivers?

Tags: networking

I have host which want to stream music to some receivers on the same local network using multicast. I think that this host need a multicast address from MADCAP. But what about the receivers? They don't need a multicast address I think, just an ordinary ip address and then they have to join the group from the host. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multicast is super simple if everything is on the same local network (that is, the same IPv4 subnet and same Ethernet multicast/broadcast domain).

Just pick an unused address from the link-local multicast control block (224.0.0.0/24), such as the experimental address 224.0.0.254. The machine sending the multicast music stream will send it to that address (that is, 224.0.0.254 will be the destination address). The source address will be the stream-senders own IPv4 unicast address.

The receivers don't need multicast addresses of their own. They just open up UDP listener sockets, bind them to the multicast address they want to listen to, and then use setsockopt to tell the kernel they want to join a multicast group.

I don't think you need to mess with MADCAP until you get to the point of wanting this streaming to work across subnets.